# Python number game with changing feeback

Tags: python, numbers

User guesses four digit number and feedback needs to be 'F' if a number is correct but not in the right place, 'X' if the number is not in the number at all and if the digit is correct and in the right position it displays the digit. Code below shows my attempt but it is giving me the error: expected str instance, list found

```
from random import randint


def check_char(a, b):   #Function making output display F, number and X depending on user input

    if a == b:
        return randomNumber         #Number is displayed when correctly guessed
    elif b == randomNumber:
        return 'F'                  #F means number is somewhere in the randomNumber
    elif b != randomNumber:
        return 'X'                  #X means number is nowhere in the randomNumber

guessesTaken = 1

randomNumber = [str(randint(1, 9))  for _ in range(4)] # create list of random nums
print(randomNumber)

while guessesTaken < 10:

    guesses = list(input("Guess Number: ")) # create list of four digits
    check = ''.join([check_char(int(a), int(b)) for a, b in zip(guesses, randomNumber)])
    if check == "YYYY": # if check has four Y's we have a correct guess
        print("Congratulations, you are correct, it took you", guessesTaken, "guesses.")
            break
    else:
        guessesTaken += 1 # else increment guess count and ask again
            print(check)
    if guessesTaken == 10:
        print("You lose")
```

Comment: Indentation matters in Python.  You need to indent the contents of `check_char`.  Right now, your code is invalid, because `check_char` is empty.  I assume you have it indented in your actual program, but can you update it here so we can see what your function is?

Comment: It is profoundly unhelpful to remove all of the *actual content* from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be replacing X with F if the user has guessed a number and it is in  randomNumber at another position it will be replaced with an ``F:

```
from random import randint    

guessesTaken = 1

randomNumber = [str(randint(1, 9))  for _ in range(4)] # create list of random nums

def check_char(a, b):   #Function making output display F, number and X depending on user input
    if a == b:
        return b        #Number is displayed when correctly guessed
    elif a in randomNumber and a != b: # if 
        return 'F'                  
    elif a != b:
        return 'X'
while guessesTaken < 10:

    guesses = list(raw_input("Guess Number: ")) # create list of four digits
    check = ''.join([check_char(a, b) for a, b in zip(guesses, randomNumber)])
    if check.isdigit(): # if check is all digits, number is guessed
        print("Congratulations, you are correct, it took you", guessesTaken, "guesses.")
        break
    else:
        guessesTaken += 1 # else increment guess count and ask again
        print(check)
else:
    print("You lose")
```

You don't need to cast as ints in `check_char(a, b)` as strings will compare just fine `"1" == "1" is True`

You are returning the list `return randomNumber`  not the substring `b` so you get an error trying to `join` as it expects a string not a list, also `b` would never be equal to `randomNumber`  .

Comment: thats perfect! but how do i stop this from happening (the way the numbers scroll down like that?) and also when i get the correct number it does that plus says i win and lose?:          ['5', '2', '8', '1']
Guess Number: 2518
2 5
5 2
1 8
8 1
FFFF

Comment: ['2', '8', '1', '5']
Guess Number: 2815                                                         
                                                                        2 2
8 8
1 1
5 5
Congratulations, you are correct, it took you 1 guesses.
You lose

Comment: @Brad,  I had missed an else, the code was edited earlier with the correct version, you are using the first version

Comment: Actually it seems to not be returning the correct feedback (the feedback for this should be 'XXXX'):            ['3', '5', '2', '5']
    Guess Number: 1678
    FFFF

Comment: try it now, mixed up a and b